# VBA　配列の処理について

Tags: vba

使用しているセル範囲を配列に格納し、
処理を行おうとしていますが、if文で文字列の比較ができていない状態です。
If r(i, 2) Like "MB*" Then　を　If r(i, 2).value Like "MB*" Then
としてみても、「オブジェクトが必要です」というエラーになってしまいます。
どういうことでしょうか？

```
 r = Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    For i = 1 To lastRow
        If r(i, 2) Like "MB*" Then
            r(i, 2) = r(i, 2) & "/" & r(i, 3)
            r(i, 5) = r(i, 5) * 8
        Else
            r(i, 2) = r(i, 2) & "/" & r(i, 3)
            r(i, 5) = r(i, 5) * 8 / 1000
        End If
    Next
    
    Range("A1:F" & lastRow) = r
```

Comment: lastRowの値は何でしょうか？　ワークシートの値がどうなっているのかも示してください。

Comment: lastRowには、最終行が入っていました。for文の前に、lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Rowで求めてあります。

Comment: ループも行われていますし、Range("A1:F" & lastRow) = r　というコードも実行されております。全て、else の中の命令が実行されているようです。

Comment: ブレークポイントを設定して、r(i, 2)の値がどうなってるか確認してみては？

Comment: If r(i, 2) Like "MB*" Then　ではなく、If r(i, 6) Like "MB*" Then とすべきですた。比較するセルが間違っておりました。有難うございました。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

比較するセルが間違っていたのが原因で、以下の通り修正しました。

**修正前:**

```
If r(i, 2) Like "MB*" Then
```

**修正後:**

```
If r(i, 6) Like "MB*" Then
```